# Nominees float over footer

Tags: bug, election, election-page

On the [Sci-Fi's election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) I found that when you vote on the nominees and then scroll down that your choices on the right hand side continue to float even over the footer.

[image: Election Bug]
<sub>(I changed my votes for the purpose of the visualization, they are not my actual votes, sorry guys)</sub>

Minor Bug I know, but still a bug, even if it is just a layout issue.

Comment: So what *are* your actual votes? ;-)

Comment: One thing after another with the SFF election

Comment: I was going to thank you for voting for me, but then I saw your note and now I am a sad frog

Comment: if you were a sad panda I may have had to change one of my votes, frogs just aren't as cute and cuddly as pandas, @JasonBaker.

Comment: [Nonsense](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Oxz.jpg), I'm adorable

Comment: Other sidebar elements also overlap the footer, eg. the related questions when asking a question.