# "How to ask" side panel floats over footer when asking a question

Tags: bug, status-declined

On all the Stack Exchange sites, when asking a question, the sidebar block which explains formatting floats over the footer.

[image: Asking example]

It is probably related with *[Nominees float over footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273898/nominees-float-over-footer)*.

Comment: @Oded could you please fix behavior in [related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290930/339911)?